# Make Error installing radare2 on alpine linux

Tags: compiling, make, alpine-linux, github

I'm running an alpine linux box, and am trying to install [radare2](https://www.radare.org/r/). I downloaded the git repo, then ran the install.sh script. It seems to run fine until running into an error:

```
In file included from p/native/linux/linux_debug.c:6:
/home/nomad/GitRepos/radare2/libr/include/r_debug.h:609:115: note: expected 'r_ptrace_data_t' {aka 'int'} but argument is of type 'void *'
 static inline long r_debug_ptrace(RDebug *dbg, r_ptrace_request_t request, pid_t pid, void *addr, r_ptrace_data_t data) {
                                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
CC linux_coredump.c
p/native/linux/linux_coredump.c:10:10: fatal error: asm/ptrace.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/ptrace.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [/home/nomad/GitRepos/radare2/libr/../global.mk:36: p/native/linux/linux_coredump.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:13: foo] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:157: debug] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:28: all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:61: all] Error 2
```

I've had a look around online, but haven't been able to find much relating to "Error 2". From the error it looks like I'm missing a library, but I'm not sure what library it is, or how to install it as I'm relatively new to alpine linux.

Comment: fatal error: asm/ptrace.h:  No such file. ....  Is a kernel header. Example location: `/usr/src/kernel-devel-5.0.2//arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Alpine Linux, the `asm/ptrace.h` header is provided by the [`linux-headers`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.10/main/x86_64/linux-headers) package.

For installing the Linux headers package, run the following:

`apk add linux-headers`

Then, try repeating the install process.